# Codename One Generic Spinner width is wrong

Tags: codenameone

I have a spinner in which I contain 5 text items: `High, Moderate, Average, Below average, Low`

At the moment I have the Spinner inside a Flow Layout container and the internal width does not appear to be sufficient to show the text contained within:

[image]

How can I make it display with the correct width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setRenderingPrototype("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");`